# JSON ARRAY Retrieve

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an Array thats pulling back about 20 sets of items from a JSON FILE:

```
 $.getJSON('jsonfile.json', function(data){
        var variable = data.twenty_items;
```

But I only wanted lets say 5 to be retrieved
-Or maybe i wanted only 10 to be called back

can someone help me with this..How do i approach this?

Comment: The data is sent from server, and you can change what is sent to you in server-side code. Show us that code.

Comment: you should probably handle this on the ServerSide. by adding a querystring to the .getJSON Request.  `$.getJSON('jsonfile.json?numberofItem=10', function (data) { var variable = data.twenty_items; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the extra items in your code.
For example:

```
arr = arr.slice(0, 5);
```

If you want to save the bandwidth, you'll need to write a server-side script that parses the JSON and returns a subset of it.

Comment: Can you show me an example where about 10 items is define, but im only grabbing 5 items??

Comment: "content":
 [
 
 
   {
   "name": "John",
   "age": "21",
   "city": "Jerset",
   "country": "USA"
  
   },
   {
   "name": "John2",
   "age": "21",
   "city": "Jerset",
   "country": "USA"
  
   },
   {
   "name": "John3",
   "age": "21",
   "city": "Jerset",
   "country": "USA"
  
   },
   {
   "name": "John4",
   "age": "21",
   "city": "Jerset",
   "country": "USA"
  
   },
   {
   "name": "John5",
   "age": "21",
   "city": "Jerset",
   "country": "USA"
  
   }

]

}

Comment: @john: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice

Comment: Can i have a proper example of this?